# Mostrar un modal con jquery tomando una clase de referencia

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap, modal

Buenos días estoy tratando de mostrar un modal al cargar una pagina tomando una clase de referencia,lo que quiero lograr es mostrar el modal en una solo una página y en las demás no lo que se me acurre es tomar una clase de referencia y mostrar el modal si existe esa clase en la página

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
      document.getElementById('hoteles').load( function() {
      //$(window).load(function(){
         $('#myModal').modal('show').delay(30000).fadeOut('fast');
      });
)};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

lo estaba tratando de hacer así pero me da error obviamente

Comment: ¿Qué error te da?

Comment: Asumo que "clase de referencia" es en realidad "id de referencia"

Comment: Esto lo quiero hacer en un CMS "Magento" @PabloLozano y solo puedo tomar un clase que contiene el body

Comment: Lo digo porque has buscando el ID hoteles, no la clase. Y lo mismo con myModal

Comment: Si es cierto pero lo ando probando local pero cuando lo suba solo podré tomar una clase como tal para mostrar el modal que es lo unico de donde pe puedo Guiar

Comment: myModal es el modal como tal y hoteles es el id que intento tomar como referencia para mostrar el modal

Comment: @PabloLozano ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No deberías mezclar Javascript a secas con jQuery, prueba a hacer algo como:

```
$(function () {
    if ($('#hoteles').length) { // o, si buscas una clase, '.hoteles'
      $('#myModal').modal('show').delay(30000).fadeOut('fast');
    }
});
```

De este modo, si no hay un elemento con la id (o la clase) `hoteles`, sencillamente no hará nada, pero no dará un error.